# MongoDB - Inc a number at a specific position in an array

Tags: mongodb, discord.js

I have a problem with my database. I would like to increment a number at a special position in my array.

Look at the picture!

https://zupimages.net/up/20/21/dqg4.png

```
await serverDB.set(message.guild.id, { "$position": 0 }, { $inc: { "QUANTITY": 1}})
```

---

Update a field in an array :

https://zupimages.net/up/20/21/pomj.png

I would like to replace 'oldName' with 'newName' in the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update your quantity array by position, you just need to mention the index in the query

```
db.getCollection('collection_name').update(
   {"_id" : ObjectId("5ec28d9058bb32681c121abe")},
   { $inc: { "QUANTITY.0": 1 } })
```

When you want to update any other field just use $set

```
db.getCollection('collection_name').update(
   {"_id" : ObjectId("5ec28d9058bb32681c121abe")},
   { $set: { "NAME.0": "newName" } })
```

Comment: Also, You know how to do the same thing but with a string, replace this string with another ?

Comment: on the id you could go with `_id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(message.guild.id)`